# Comparing two time period of same binary variables

Tags: r, time-series, binary-data, sas, change-point

We are a financial institution which falls under this ‘Big Bank’ category. As a part of our routine analysis on input variables that feed several of our risk models, we would like to setup an input monitoring system that can trigger any drastic changes in the trend/pattern in our input variables over different period of time spanning from 2007 to 2013. We have decent understanding on how to perform this analysis on continuous variables, but we don’t know how to do this on binary variables that has two outcome (yes=1, No=0). I would like to take the same variable at different time period (for e.g  Var1 from Jan2007 to Jan2008 Vs Var1 from Jan2008 to Jan2009) and see if there is a significant change in the trend/distribution. I would assume my question boil down to a point where we are comparing the binomial distribution of the same variable at two different time periods. If I do that I am  afraid my samples won't be independent to each other, that threw away the option of using Chi-Squared test, What’s the right strategy to perform this analysis,  how do I carry out this test preferably in SAS, if SAS doesn’t have right procedure or function, then R will be the next choice.

Comment: Could you please formulate the null and alternative hypotheses of such test and explain why they would be useful?

Comment: The Null is probability distribution of a given variable for time period-1 equal time period-2, Alternate hypothesis is distribution of time period-1 is significantly different from period-2. Why it is usefull? answer is the Null under which several models were built is no longer valid in case we reject this hypothesis

Comment: Ok. Now this identifies a potential problem with your alternative. Using classic tests would have the alternative 'there is a difference in distribution'. Not 'there is a significant difference'. Thus, using huge sample sizes will cause any tiny irrelevant difference to reject the null. Maybe you want to allow a certain tolerance before you would call a rejected null a 'drastic trend'.

Comment: Take a look at McNemar's test. proc freq; table T1*T2/exact mcnem; run;